# How do you assign sequential IP addresses to individual ports on a switch?

Tags: switch, ipv4, static

I am looking for a non-complicated way to set up a network of 50 interchangeable devices such that whenever I plug a device into a specific port on a switch, I will always get the same IP address based on which port I plugged in to. Even if different devices are plugged into that same port on the switch. This will help me keep track of which device is where.

This will help me locate any troublesome devices instead of having to look at each one and figure out what it's serial number is. I can know by which port it is physically plugged in where it shows up on my rack.

This is on a very isolated network that will be plugged into a single computer. I'm thinking of having a simple router and a simple 52 port switch. But I need the IP addresses to not change whenever I change which device is plugged in.

I do not want to use vlans I do not want it to be complicated. I just want simple IP4 addresses in order.

Is this a simple thing or am I trying to do something that no one ever has tried before? I am having trouble finding a simple way to do this.

Comment: DHCP option 82. The switch needs to tell the dhcp server what port sourced the request. This will fall apart if someone plugs a switch/hub into a port.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with a normal switch and dhcp server, the dhcp server does not know which port the device is plugged in to.

Some higher-end switches do seem to offer functionality to support this though. Googling "port based dhcp" seems to find some leads.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to use vlans I do not want it to be complicated. I just want simple IP4 addresses in order.

As the song says, "You can't always get what you want."

Switches, being layer 2 devices, only forward Ethernet frames, and have no knowledge of IP addresses.

It would be possible to do this with VLANS, but it is rather complicated.